# How to install and configure Laravel with MongoDB on Windows

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I am trying to install Laravel with MongoDB on wamp server.

Comment: Good luck! If there's any specific problem, please feel free to give us some details...

Comment: Sure, Thanks  for comment

Answer (score 0):

Did you test [laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb)?

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot